# php-5.3.1-Win32-VC9-x86.zip alternative download location?

Tags: php, windows

http://windows.php.net is currently down, it seems (gives me 404 error). Anyone knows where I can download php-5.3.1-Win32-VC9-x86.zip? When windows.php.net is expected to be up?

Thanks.

P.S. Isn't this a question for serverfault? Couldn't decide for sure...

Comment: Well, seeing as it's about a server fault... :) But no, I think it belongs here.

Comment: It's not the first time I see a question such as this one on SO, and I have never felt any need to mark it as "belongs somewhere else" -- so I'd say, too, that's it's OK here.

Comment: It seems windows.php.net is back :-)  (posting this as a comment, so the asker sees it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT (somewhere 00h30 UTC) : it seems it's back ;-)**

There is an update that's being gone on the windows.php.net server ; see [this tweet](http://twitter.com/PierreJoye/status/7523238021) from [@PierreJoye](http://twitter.com/PierreJoye) :

> doing a major update of wiki and
>   windows.php.net box. Pls stop to bomb
>   mails everyone :) 
> *about 5 hours
>   ago*

For the "*When windows.php.net is expected to be up?*" part : well, when the update is finished, I'd say ^^

For an alternate download location... Sorry, I have no idea -- the server should come back at some point...

Can you wait a couple of hours ?

If yes, I'd recommend waiting until the official download location comes back on.

Comment: You're welcome :-) (always useful to follow PHP-developpers on twitter ^^ )

Comment: Yea.. I would follow them too ;) If there wouldn't be so much crap around useful posts ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's sometimes a problem -- I'm not following (or have un-followed) some interesting guys, because of that :-( -- but I can't spend my whole day filtering what's going on on twitter ^^